# How to compute Stack usage on TI processor from the LST files?

Tags: stack, instruction-set, texas-instruments

The .lst file gives FR SIZE for each function used in the code.
Can I consider that as the stack usage in Words?

I am trying to find any supporting document for this, but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

The FR SIZE provides the stack size usage created due to the auto/local variables and the function parameters.

Stack Size modified with other stack operations are not included in this FR SIZE.